# Haskell Error; Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t ~ [t]

Tags: haskell, ghci

I asked a few questions yesterday and more and more problems kept creeping up in my code.

I have a function called sub. Sub takes in a number and outputs a list of numbers, the code is below.

```
sub 5 =  [1]
sub x =
    do 
        xs <- sub (x - 1)
        (x:xs)
```

I used to have to where on the top line had sub 5 = return [1] and on the bottom line, return (x:xs). Someone answered yesterday and told me to take these out as it's putting a list within a list, like so [[int]]. If I take out  the returns this generates an error (In the question title), I really can't get my head around this.

Just wondering if anyone can make sense of it,

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to expand what the error means.

Lets desugar do notation ([details](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation)):

```
sub 5 =  [1]
sub x =
        sub (x - 1) >>= \xs ->
        (x:xs)
```

The `>>=` operator has the next type (see [here](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28%3E%3E=%29)):

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

The first its argument, `sub (x - 1)`, has type `[Int]`, so we can instantiate type variables `m` to `[]` and `a` to `Int`:

```
(>>=) :: [Int] -> (Int -> [b]) -> [b]
```

(Note that `[a]` is a special syntax for list type, you can read it as `[] a`)

So the second argument, `\xs -> (x:xs)`, should have type `Int -> [b]`. It should be clear now that `xs` has type `Int`, not `[Int]` as you seems to expect.

Now lets consider `:`. Its type is `c -> [c] -> [c]`. Let write down all constrains:

```
(:)     :: c -> [c] -> [c]
x       :: Int
xs      :: Int
x : xs  :: [Int]
```

They can't be satisfied at the same time because they require `c` and `[c]` both to be `Int`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, Yuras. I understand the errors a bit better now, still have no clue how to fix it. But i'll try a few things later. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Let's rewrite what you have to make clearer why this won't typecheck. We first desugar the do notation to get

```
sub :: Int -> [Int]
sub 5 = [1]
sub x = sub (x-1) >>= \xs -> (x:xs)
```

Now recall how `>>=` is defined for lists: `ys >>= f = concat (map f ys)`. Here `f` is `\xs -> (x:xs)` and `ys` is `sub (x-1)`, so therefore we have:

```
sub :: Int -> [Int]
sub 5 = [1]
sub x = concat (map (\xs -> (x:xs)) (sub (x-1)))
```

The type of `sub (x-1)` is `[Int]`, so the first argument to `map` must be a function that takes an `Int`. It is not - it expects a list!

As you say, you used to have `sub 5 = return [1]`. Recall that for lists `return y = [y]`, so in that case your `sub` would have signature `Int -> [[Int]]`. Now `sub (x-1)` in the above would be a list of lists, and the first argument to `map` should be a function that takes *lists*, which is indeed the case. So things typechecked.

A piece of advice: Give your top-level definitions explicit signatures (is it `sub :: Int -> [Int]` or `sub :: Int -> [[Int]]` that you want?)! It'll make it easier to understand what's going on because it forces you to think about what you actually want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Paired with Yuras's answer it's really helped me understand.